# Deleting space between date and letterhead logo

Tags: spacing, letters, letterhead

I'm writing a cover letter and trying to keep it at two pages, but I can't get rid of the huge white space between the logo and date. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,article, times, addrfromright]{newlfm}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\unprbottom{1cm}

\makeatletter

\g@addto@macro{\ps@ltrhead}{%

 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\g@addto@macro{\ps@othhead}{%

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lastpage,calc}

\newsavebox{\Ltlfoot}

\sbox{\Ltlfoot}{\tiny Robert Schuman Center for Advanced Studies

  European University Institute, Via dei Roccettini 9, I-50014 San Domenico di Fiesole (FI) Italy}}
\newlength{\myfootheight}
\settoheight{\myfootheight}{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{.5in}
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{both2}}}

\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{%

\Lfooter{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}%

 \Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\Rfooter{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\lfooter{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}

\rfooter{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=5pt, minfoot=\myfootheight}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}

\lthUiuc
\namefrom{blah \\
job \\
Robert Schuman Centre for Advanced Studies \\
European }
\addrfrom{
    name\\
    job\\
    Studies
}
\emailfrom{email@email}


\addrto{%
address \\
}

\greetto{Dear Members of the Search Committee:}
\closeline{Best Regards,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
```

Comment: It is useful, if you add a picture with where you want less space. Also, please use the standard classes like article, letter, book, report for a MWE.

Comment: This is no MWE. Please provide a full working MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}
```

with

```
\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}\vspace{-200pt}}
```

You can use any value you want. It worked on me.